# AWS API - How to get main route table ID by subnet ID? association.subnet-id filter doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services

I need to get the ID of a subnet's main route table, so I can add more routes.
That route table is implicitly associated (therefore main).

I am using the: `aws ec2 describe-route-tables` with this filter: `--filters "Name=association.subnet-id,Values=<subnet_id>"` however this filter works only on explicit associations.

I could use the: `association.main` filter, however in my VPC I've got more than one Main route table, so this wouldn't work in my case.

**Update: Above statement is incorrect, hence my source of troubles**

Documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-route-tables.html

> "If a subnet is not explicitly associated with any route table, it is
> implicitly associated with the main route table. This command does not
> return the subnet ID for implicit associations."

Is there any workaround?

When I manually get the route table id (using the web interface) I can retrieve it just fine: `--filters "Name=association.route-table-id,Values=rtb-<>"`:

```
{
    "RouteTables": [
        {
            "Associations": [
                {
                    "Main": true,
                    "RouteTableAssociationId": "rtbassoc-<>",
                    "RouteTableId": "rtb-<>",
                    "AssociationState": {
                        "State": "associated"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "PropagatingVgws": [],
            "RouteTableId": "rtb-<>",
            "Routes": [
                {
                    "DestinationCidrBlock": "10.109.0.0/16",
                    "GatewayId": "local",
                    "Origin": "CreateRouteTable",
                    "State": "active"
                }
            ],
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": ""
                }
            ],
            "VpcId": "vpc-<>",
            "OwnerId": "<>"
        }
    ]
}
```

It's just I need to obtain the route table id via API means, not the web interface.

Comment: There is only 1 main route table per vpc right, do you have vpc id to fetch its route table? if not, get the vpc of the given subnet and then get its main route table?

Comment: Thank you, I was making wrong assumption that every subnet has implicit main route table, which isn't true. I've added answer based on your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've incorrectly assumed that there is more than one main subnet within VPC.

Given that there is just one main subnet in the VPC, here is how you can fetch main table route ID:
`aws ec2 describe-route-tables --filters "Name=association.main,Values=true" "Name=vpc-id,Values=<vpc-id>" --query=RouteTables[*].RouteTableId --output=text`